# Test a website to see if all the links/URL's (XHR URL's) are working fine

Tags: java, performance, testing, build, jmeter

It may sound like a naive issue but I can't find a perfect solution for this.

***My solution:***

1. Copy every single URL.
2. Paste it in Jmeter.
3. Run Jmeter after every
   build.

Surely, there must be a better solution.

Comment: Yeah: write functional/end2end tests that cover all the relevant APIs.

Comment: @luk2302: Thanks. Can you please suggest some technologies that I can use?

Comment: They are just a little bit more complicated then unit or integration tests, you can just use the normal junit, assertj, ... stuff to write and run them.

Comment: @luk2302 : I don't have access to the code. I can only access the website.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this fit to your question. On my end when I test and search for broken links to my website I used "xenulink" tools. It is a bit old but still works fine on my end

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

JMeter comes with [HTML Link Parser](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) which can be used for automatic checking for "dead" links

> **Spidering Example**
>
> Consider a simple example: let's say you wanted JMeter to "spider" through your site, hitting link after link parsed from the HTML returned from your server (this is not actually the most useful thing to do, but it serves as a good example). You would create a [Simple Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller), and add the "HTML Link Parser" to it. Then, create an HTTP Request, and set the domain to ".*", and the path likewise. This will cause your test sample to match with any link found on the returned pages. If you wanted to restrict the spidering to a particular domain, then change the domain value to the one you want. Then, only links to that domain will be followed.

You may also find [How to Spider a Site with JMeter - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial) article useful.